# Getting the number of matching sums in a list using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
def number_ties(my_list, for_it=[], against=[],ties=0,k=0):
    if len(my_list)==0:
        return ties
    j=my_list[0]
    del my_list[0]
    if sum(list(for_it))==sum(list(against)) and k>0:
        ties+=1
    k+=1
    return number_ties(my_list,for_it+[j],against,ties,k)+number_ties(my_list,for_it,against+[j],ties,k)
```

Using recursion, I'm trying to take a list of numbers and find out how many ways I can put different combinations of these numbers for and against something ( a vote for example ) and achieve a tie. For example [1,2,3] can tie in 2 ways i.e [1,2] against [3] and [3] against [1,2]. Similarly [1, 1, 2, 3, 5] should tie in 4 ways. ( Same numbers within the list should be considered different votes.Like people with different voting weights, for example.) 
My code above doesnt work. How may I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I have posted the code. I have also described what I am trying to do with the code above. My question was why the code above didnt work. What more may I describe? @Prune

Comment: Again, follow the posting guidelines.  Provide the MCVE and the actual output; you've given us the desired output.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that. This was a definition for a function. Thats why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting problem of summing up combinations to half the total sum of your list is more suitable for a recursive implementation:

```
def number_ties(lst):
    s = sum(lst)
    if s % 2:
        return 0  # sum must be even for it to work at all
    half = s // 2
    return sum_count(lst, half)


def sum_count(lst, total):  # number of combinations out of lst that sum to total
    if not lst:  # base case
        return int(total == 0)  # empty lst and total 0 -> return 1
    # recur: add ways with first element and ways without
    return sum_count(lst[1:], total) + sum_count(lst[1:], total-lst[0])

> print(number_ties([1, 2, 3]))
2
> print(number_ties([1, 1, 2, 3, 5]))
4
```

Comment: Thank you so much !! Thats very clear :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, re-cast this as a slightly simpler problem: you have to find combinations of elements that sum to half of the array sum.  This is called the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

The basic idea is "simple".

```
Given: array, target
Grab the first array element, array[0]
if target == 0
    success; you're done
else if target < 0
    failure
else  # recur both with and without the first element
    solution_with = recur using (array[1:end], target - array[0]);
                    append array[0]
    solution_not  = recur using (array[1:end], target)
```

Does that get you moving?
        recur

Comment: Okay. What is target?

Comment: The target value: half the sum of the original array.  You reduce it every time you choose an element.